# Best way to insert a new value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use a pandas dataframe to keep track of some market data I will be downloading live during the trading day.

Let's say I want to log the prices of AAPL and GOOG. I start by creating a dataframe:

```
prices = DataFrame(columns = ['AAPL', 'GOOG'])
```

Let's say the first datapoint comes in at at time t1 and price 555.0 for AAPL.  And then a few seconds later at t2, a price of 430.0 comes in for GOOG.

One of course can't do:

```
prices['AAPL'][t1] = 555.0
prices['GOOG'][t2] = 430.0
```

Is there an easy/fast way in pandas to accomplish this though besides pulling the index, modifying it, reindexing the dataframe and then inserting each scalar price as it comes in?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `set_value` method (which returns a reference to a new object if the size if mutated). But don't expect it to be fast (compared with a nested dict):

```
In [7]: prices
Out[7]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: array([AAPL, GOOG], dtype=object)
Index: array([], dtype=object)

In [8]: prices = prices.set_value(t1, 'AAPL', 5)

In [9]: prices
Out[9]: 
                            AAPL  GOOG
2012-04-12 18:02:28.178331     5   NaN
```

It would be nice to add a method at some point for more efficiently resizing a DataFrame by gluing on data at the end (NumPy does have a facility for this).

Comment: Thanks!  I guess if speed becomes an issue, then as you said create a nested dict, and then convert to a dataframe at some point.