# python pandas set_value not persistent?

Tags: python, pandas, setvalue

I'm trying to write a small program in Python keeping track of a equity portfolio over a year, so basically registering every buy/sell, and keeping track of the balance. I'm going through a list of orders and update Pandas dataframe, where I keep the portfolio. The code looks pretty obscure but I'm quite new to Pandas/numpy:

```
orders_book = DataFrame(np.zeros((num_of_days,num_of_companies+1)), ldt_timestamps, columns = book_keys)

for equity_sym in ls_symbols[1:2]:
    for trade_date in ldt_timestamps:
        if trade_date == ldt_timestamps[0]:
            current_number = orders_book.xs(trade_date)[equity_sym]
        for transaction in trades:
            transaction_date = transaction[0]
            transaction_sym  = transaction[1]
            if ( ( trade_date == transaction_date ) and (equity_sym == transaction_sym ) ):
                transaction_order  = transaction[2]
                transaction_number =  transaction[3]
                if str(transaction_order) == 'Buy':
                    current_number += transaction_number
                if str(transaction_order) == 'Sell':
                    current_number -= transaction_number
        orders_book.ix[trade_date,equity_sym, current_number] = current_number
```

[equity_sym]
I kept the comments to convince you that I by printing in the runtime I checked that this complicated loop works OK (as you see, I update `orders_book` using `set_value`). However, when the loop ends, and I try simply `print orders_book['GOOG']`, then `orders_book` looks just like at the beginning, i.e., before loop. Why is that? Would appreciate your help :)

EDIT:
The code is changed now and works properly. It was not Panda's fault but wrong placement of the updating/writing function in the code. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: The semantics of `set_value` seems to be obscure, it may create a new DataFrame.

Comment: try doing something like `orders_book.ix[trade_date, equity_sym] = current_number` instead

Comment: @ChangShe: unfortunately did't help

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132552/419338) by Pandas' author, `set_value` returns a reference to a new object. You need to use `concat`  or `append` to add rows to a data table. See section  ["Merge, join, and concatenate"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) in the Pandas manual.

Comment: But if I'd rather modify than add?